# Display the last 13 numbers in cell along with any letters after those 13 numbers

Tags: excel

I need to pull out the last 13 numbers in a cell and if it has letters at the end I need them too.  This will be a daily task and they are all in the same column.

Example:

```
niin_id=14415288
nsn=1680014415288FW
```

out of this cell, I am needing it to return with

```
1680014415288FW
```

Some have the 2 letters after the number and some do not. On the ones that do not have the 2 letters I need it to just pull back the last 13 numbers.

Comment: This will prob be easier with VBA

Comment: is the `niin_id=14415288` treated as it's own cell or does it share a cell with the `nsn=1680014415288FW`? The numbers are not 13 long, so I'm not sure how you expect this to be evaluated.

Comment: all data is in one cell

Comment: Mark S., thanks, I'll try that now.

Comment: Does it always follow the last `=`?

Comment: Mark S, I did try that, It brought back everything after the first "=", I am needing the last 13-15 after the second "=" in the cell.  Is there a way to clean that up to work?

Comment: What do you mean by the `last 13-15`? Seems to work OK on your sample.

Comment: @FishingTime the way you have the question it's unclear that the data was only in one cell. Is there any other consistencies such as the same `nsn` or something we can use?

Comment: @FishingTime I fixed my answer to reflect the new information you gave us. in future, please clarify nuance like this to get better answers, faster.

Comment: @FishingTime Has the solution worked??

Answer (score 1):

If the data you want kept always follows the last `=` in a cell then:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"=","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"=",""))))+1,999)
```

[image]

---

If your version has FILTERXML:

```
=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"=","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[last()]")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in A1 and that you always want the string after the = (the last 13-15 characters).

Based on new information that `niin_id=14415288nsn=1680014415288FW` is one cell, here is the adjusted formula.

`=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("=",A1,9))`